# Print out list of function parameters in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to print out a function's parameter list?
For example:

```
def func(a, b, c):
  pass

print_func_parametes(func)
```

Which will produce something like:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the inspect module.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(func)
(['a', 'b', 'c'], None, None, None)
```

The first part of returned tuple is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Read the source.  Seriously.  Python programs and libraries are provided as source.  You can read the source.

Comment: Unless the O.P. is writing some code analysis/development tool, I am guessing that whatever they need it for will end in disaster.

Answer (score 2):

You might also try the built-in `help()` function, which will provide you not only with a list of the named parameters, but also a description of `func()` if you provided a docstring:

```
>>> def func(a, b, c):
...     """do x to a,b,c and return the result"""
...     pass
... 
>>> help(func)
```

gives you

```
    
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(a, b, c)
    do x to a,b,c and return the result
```

Most modules are provided with at least some sort of built-in documentation.